# Comparing dates in Sql

Tags: sql

I am having trouble trying to compare dates in my sql query:

```
SELECT restrictions, restrictions_adddate FROM restrictions WHERE id = '555555'
AND restrictions_adddate BETWEEN ? and ?;
```

Both of the parameters system print in the format  'mm-dd-yyyy'.  I am getting a wrong date format error, but have tried doing it in multiple ways.  Any help is appreciated, and if more info is needed, please let me know.  thanks.

Comment: did you also try the format "yyyy-mm-dd"?

Comment: yes, I tried this as well, I get a literal does not match string error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , Oracle11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on any standard compliant DBMS:

```
SELECT restrictions, restrictions_adddate 
FROM restrictions 
WHERE id = '555555'
  AND restrictions_adddate BETWEEN DATE '2011-01-01' and DATE '2011-12-31';
```

Comment: @Dems: that is not true. The format `DATE '2011-01-01'` is defined by the ANSI standard such that the literal is required to be in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd). If you leave out the keyword `DATE` then you are absolutely right.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Actually *it is* true. SQL Server when in British English mode inteprets this format as 'yyyy-dd-mm' unless you add a time part e.g. "2012-07-13T00:00:00"

Comment: @Trekstuff: then SQL Server badly violates the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the `CONVERT` function T-SQL reference in BOL. You should be able to use this dictate the format of your dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is my preference:

```
AND restrictions_adddate BETWEEN
    CONVERT(datetime, FLOOR(CONVERT(float, CAST('01-01-1900' AS DATETIME))))
    AND CONVERT(datetime, FLOOR(CONVERT(float, Getdate())));
```

This allows you to compare dates (minus the time stamps).

Comment: I tried this, but I am unfamiliar with most of the terms.  How exactly is this comparing the dates?

Comment: He's taking a date with a time and removing the time part.  which isn't really pasrt of your question.

Comment: @Dems, the questions was how to compare two dates. Regardless of whether I'm removing the time or not, that's what the code does. My example shows how to use the current date, as well as any date that you want to plug in as a string - '01-01-1900'.